# HMatrix Matrix Double - Double product

Tags: haskell, hmatrix

```
f1 :: Mesh -> Matrix Double
f1 me = knx where
  hx :: Double
  (hx , _) = h me
  a, knx :: Matrix Double
  a = fromLists [[1,2], [3,4]] 
  knx = hx * a 
  -- knx = 2 * a
```

I don't get why in the above function, mutliplying by 2 works whereas multiplying by hx = 0.5 doesn't. OTOH, multiplying a `Matrix Double` with a `Double` *outside* a function works as it should.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Matrix Double’
            with actual type ‘Double’
In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘hx’
In the expression: hx * a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am seriously puzzled. Any pointers are welcome!

Comment: So you are puzzled, and want us to be puzzled as well? Give all of the types and functions definitions involved, we are not telepaths (well, majority of us).

Comment: I though it would be pretty much self-contained: the `h` function retrieves a tuple of doubles from a 'Mesh' datastruct (whose internals are not necessary here). The only error in the code above is in the computation of `knx`

Comment: Don't you think, that for a comprehensive answer people should be able at least try and reproduce the error (well, it' not always the case, but you should provide the possibility)?

Comment: (*) has type: (Num a) => a -> a -> a so I highly doubt you could multiply a Matrix Double with a Double anywhere in your code. I think the number you thought as Double outside of this function is actually gets inferred as a 1x1 matrix. Unfortunately I don't have a ghci at hand to test this but I can get back in a few hours if you are still puzzled then.

Comment: You are quite right. The operation I was looking for is `scale :: Container c e => e -> c e -> c e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `HMatrix`,  `scale :: Container c e => e -> c e -> c e` does what it says on the label (multiplies the `e` in a `c e` by the first `e`). Here are some usage examples here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.16.1.4/docs/src/Data-Packed-Internal-Numeric.html

It should be noted that `scale x` constructs a Container type by considering x a singleton list, via `fromList`.

It would be really handy if at least the common arithmetic operations would be overloaded, so that formulas may resemble their mathematical counterpart. I'm not sure whether defining function synonyms (e.g. `(.*) = scale` ) would be a good idea or it would just add a layer of complexity. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the problem with overloading the (.*) for matrix x scalar product is that it doesn't associate as (*) should(and imply). E.g. the order of the arguments would matter and that would be confusing imho.